# VM ram requirement for aws s3 sync job

Tags: virtualbox, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a VM setup to sync 15TB of data split in 25GB volumes to S3 using the latest awscli v.2. I have a 100Mbps upload capacity, and the job will probably take 16 days. I haven't had any experience with this until now, I am am trying to limit the problems I might run to.

1. Is there any guess what would be the necessary RAM requirement of the VM to go through this process?
2. Is a 2 core VM OK?
3. Is there something else I might need to check before proceeding?

Thanks

Comment: A Raspberry Pi could do this.

Comment: How did it go for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 2GB of memory should totally work if you are using Linux.
2. Yes - two core are fine
3. Try to compress the files splits if possible, compression (even on 2 cores) could help you to speed up the process.

I have done this work with a 2-core 2GB machine without any problems. I compressed the files on a 12-core machine with gzip and saved another 30%.

Comment: there are duplicity volumes already encrypted and compressed. Thank you